# RESTful web service - HATEOAS

Tags: rest, web, service, hateoas

I have created a quite simple RESTful web service. It only supports the GET (=read) method, e.g.:
`http://localhost/application/id/xyz`

The corresponding information for this ID is queried from a data source and returned as JSON.
Now my question: (How) should I implement HATEOAS in this case? Does it even make sense? I understand that HATEOAS is reasonable when having a more complex structure. But in this case, there are no other resources I could link to. The client calls the web service with a certain ID and the server returns information.

Thank you!

Comment: When you mentioned about HATEOAS I thought that only one interesting data which could be returned by your RESTful Web Service it is self-referencing hyperlink like on this page : http://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS

Comment: how does the client know about the id?

Comment: Hello. The Client is an application that loads a table from an external source. One of the columns holds this ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said "The client calls the web service with a certain ID" it sounds like you've written your client to visit a specific URL in your service which has the URL to visit *generated* by the client, i.e. your client application already knows it can visit `http://localhost/application/id/xyz` for the `xyz` ID.

If you'd like to leverage some of the power of HATEOAS and decouple yourself from this (slight) dependency, you could instead be querying `http://localhost/application/id?query=xyz` which could return a list of valid links (if any exist). That way you could change the format or structure of the linked URL without issues for your client (of course, you'd still be dependent on the query URL in some way).

However, as your usage is so simple, this sounds like overkill and unnecessary work so I'd suggest you don't need to worry about HATEOAS until you have a more complex system or clients :)

Comment: I'm happy that helps :) Please could you upvote this answer as I have actually been answer-banned following this for having too many low-scoring answers! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In HATEOS your return value is not an ID but a URL.  Invoking that URL links you to the next resource in the web.  Just like a web page containing links to other web pages.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I already know that by using HATEOS, an URL should be returned. But does that make sense for my scenario? How could I achieve that this principle is fulfilled?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't make sense.  Of course no one is forcing you to use HATEOS if you don't like it.  As mentioned by GarciaPL, using spring-data makes it very easy to generate a HATEOS service, and it generates the links for you.

Comment: Thanks for your fast replies :) The reason why I am struggling about the meaningfulness of my special case is that there is no other operation available than getting information for a certain ID that is passed in the HTTP GET request.
So just for the record - if I insert a self-linking URL into my JSON, then my RESTful environment would fulfill the principle of HATEOS?

Comment: The question is does your application use hypertext as the engine of application state!

Comment: Sorry for my -very late- reply. No, it does not. As I said, I only query one kind of resource, that's it. There is no hypertext necessary, actually.

Comment: Ok then don't try to use HATEOS

Comment: Thanks for discussing! I appreciate it.

Comment: no problem, please show appreciation with some up votes.